# Actor programming model and command pattern

Tags: akka, actor, command-pattern

I want an undo/redo history in a system.  I know how to implement this using traditional OO, but I have a system prototype that seems suited to the Actor paradigm, and I like the simplicity and scalability of it, but I'm struggling to reconcile Actor messaging with the command pattern.

Should there be some kind of Command History Actor?  Perhaps I send messages about messages to that, so that it can coordinate how to undo/redo them?  Anyone who has implemented some kind of command history with Actor programming please help.

Comment: There is a video exactly about this: https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-25/show Hope it helps.